# Run install.ps1 when NOT installing in VisualStudio

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I am looking for a way to execute a script when a nuget-Package is installed, but not in a VS solution or project.

I tried to include a `install.ps1` in the tools folder, but it does not execute.

I thought it might be because I do not have any files in `lib` or `content`. So I included some dummy file into `/content` but it still does not execute.

So i changed it to an `init.ps1` just to check but it still does not execute.

Now my guess is: the *.ps1 scripts only execute if I install the package into a VS solution/project. Is this correct? I did not find anything in regard in the documentation.

I am trying to install my package in a plain folder. No projects, no solutions, no VS.

Is there a way to make nuget execute any script in my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the documentation [here](http://docs.nuget.org/create/creating-and-publishing-a-package) (Automatically Running PowerShell Scripts ) it mentions that those scripts are run in the context of a project or solution.

Most often install/uninstall action is add/remove references or files to/from the target project, so it actually makes no sence to run those without project context.

Comment: Depends on the package. My pacakge would've just juggled some files around. But I will find another solution then ... thanks.